# Weird Imagebutton result

Tags: android, imagebutton

I try to make a image button for login. But the result is weird. Please see the attachment.
[image]

The weird thing is the image button is inside the button...

Hope for helps.

this is xml code...

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chkRememberMe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:src="@drawable/login_off" />
```

this is java code for the login button...

```
imageButtonLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

imageButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
                if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
                } else {

                    String inputUserName = userNameEditText.getText()
                            .toString();
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setUsername(inputUserName);
                    contact.setPassword(inputPassword);
                    if (contactDb.searchContact(contact)) {
                        // logged in
                        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(R.string.loggedIn),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                        Intent newActivity = new Intent();
                        //go to AudioRecoder page
                        newActivity
                                .setClass(MainActivity.this, AudioActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);

                    } else {
                        // login failed
                        showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please explain, *completely and precisely*, what is "weird". Also, please provide the XML or Java where you set up the button.

Comment: Try to set the background of your `ImageButton` instead of `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
android:background="@drawable/login_off"
```

instead of src like you are.

Comment: Thank you ! It works. But how can I modify the size of the button? Looking for the help!

Comment: or just to put the background Transparent with : `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @AnthonyLo you need to make your image itself bigger. Or even better make a 9patch so it will adapt to whatever size you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chkRememberMe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
         android:src="@drawable/login_off" />
```

you can set the background or trasparent `android:background="#00FFFFFF"` or to  null `android:background="@null"`

Comment: How can I modify the size of the button?